# Wrong frame value for UIImageView made with storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a blur effect to an `UIImageView` . I placed the image into my view using storyboards and have used the following code:

```
var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
visualEffectView.frame = bigProfileImage.frame
bigProfileImage.addSubview(visualEffectView)

println(bigProfileImage.frame)
println(visualEffectView.frame)
```

This always prints:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)
```

Which is much smaller than my image. You can see the reuslt here:

[image]

What is causing the `UIImageView` to not have the correct frame when accessed via code?

Comment: ? Using autolayout ? BTW, this is inherently incorrect. Say the frame of your UIImage is not anchored at (0,0), then the subview would have an offset. Use `bigProfileImage.bounds` not `.frame`.

Comment: @LancelotdelaMare yes autolayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that your `UIImageView` has constraints set up that allow it to fill the screen, but your `UIVisualEffectView` has no such constraints. You may be setting the frame once, but the `UIImageView`'s frame likely changes afterwards.

My advice is this: Because you're using Storyboards, drag out a `UIVisualEffectView` and place it over the top of your `UIImageView` (either a subview of the `UIImageView` or the superview).  Add constraints to it that either fill the screen, or match the `UIImageView`'s frame, depending on which superview to which you added the `UIVisualEffectView`.  You could also do this in the code you have.

i.e. Add constraints that pin the top, bottom, left and right edges of the `UIVisualEffectView` to either the superview, or the `UIImageView`.

Remember that the `UIVisualEffectView` must be on top of the `UIImageView` for the blur to work.  Don't add the `UIImageView` as a subview of the `UIVisualEffectView` or its `contentView`.

Comment: when i `println(bigProfileImage.constraints())` its just an empty array.

Comment: You'll need to add constraints in your Storyboard then, or in code.